# How to create a repository in ATG?

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo

i would like to know how to create a new repository in ATG. like what all steps are needed to be included? Do i need to create a properties file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create a new repository, You need to follow these steps if you want to create a repository that uses sql database in as the datastore.

1. Create a properties file
2. Create tables you want to map to the repository
3. Create a definition XML files to map repository item-descriptors and their properties to the respective tables.

#### MyRepository.properties

```
$class=atg.adapter.gsa.GSARepository
repositoryName=MyRepository
definitionFiles=atg/test/repositories/MyRepository.xml
XMLToolsFactory=/atg/dynamo/service/xml/XMLToolsFactory
transactionManager=/atg/dynamo/transaction/TransactionManager
idGenerator=/atg/dynamo/service/IdGenerator
dataSource=/atg/dynamo/service/jdbc/JTDataSource
lockManager=/atg/dynamo/service/ClientLockManager
```

The above properties files ensures that a new repository component is created and MyRepository.xml will be marked as its definition file.

The content of the MyRepository.xml file should be something like below...

#### MyRepository.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE gsa-template SYSTEM "http://www.atg.com/dtds/gsa/gsa_1.0.dtd">
<gsa-template>
    <header>
        <name>New Repository creation</name>
        <author>Jyothi Prasad Buddha</author>
    </header>
    <item-descriptor name="myRepo" cache-mode="simple">
        <table name="my_repo" type="primary" id-column-names="id">
            <!-- properties that may (or may not) be used as primary keys -->
            <property name="name" data-types="String" />
            <property name="age" data-types="int" />
        </table>
    </item-descriptor>
</gsa-template>
```

However you will have to create the the necessary tables before you start atg instance. The above xml files refers to a table named my_repo which has comlumns name and age.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you need to create properties file's for more details you can read RepositoryGuide.pdf from Oracle.

for more detail you can read below blog
http://immuraliraj.blogspot.in/2011/12/atg-repository-basic-concepts.html

Answer (score 1):

Just type 
"**ATG Creating a repository**"  on Google
 and you would get lot of relevant results on the first page itself. Also be specific which version of ATG are you using, and what you have already done/found in your research. (just a suggestion, so you get good responses).

Yes, you need a properties file when creating a custom repository component. There are a lot of blogs that answer your question with detailed steps.

[Check this for example](http://world-of-atg.blogspot.in/2012/07/creating-your-own-atg-repository-basics.html)